# Как отобразить дочерний компонент во vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть на главной страницы компонент header в нем есть элемент burger,при клике  на него("burger") должен появляется другой компонент ("aside") с сопутствующей информацией.

Как я это хотел реализовать?
Повесить обработчик события на бургер точнее на картинку с бургером и за емитить это событие получается в дочерний компонент ("aside") где буду встречать его

Comment: Я использую стор для таких вещей. Называю его как-то типа UiState и в нём держу состояние отображения всех компонентов. Это позволяет вызывать их из любого участка проекта. В твоём случае я бы советовал поступить так же.  Нажимаешь куда надо, вызываешь мутацию, готово. И не надо в каком-то компоненте писать логику для этого. А если ещё откуда-нибудь надо будет вызвать компонент? Копипастить логику туда? Проще хранить это всё в одном месте, имхо.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: А может проще добавить бургер какой-то класс, по которому откроется меню? Зачем городить  кучу логики?

Comment: 1) Добавьте переменную burgerShow, которая по умолчанию будет у вас false; 2) На бургер повесьте @click="burgerShow = !burgerShow" 3) В вызове компонента добавьте <aside v-if="burgerShow" ...>

Comment: @Дмытрык давайте уже потихоньку уходить от toggleClass

Comment: Сделал спасибо)По toogle 
Теперь проблема в другом, при открытие сайдбара  в нем должен быть  select  и календарик, но при выборе в select.e option'a ,закрывается сайдбар и я грешу на событие которое закрывает сайд бар, решение я думаю нужно убрать toogle и cделать просто через true false и import компонента  делать в компонент бургера и показывать его через v-if или v-show